# Ionic , using ion-select and trying to pass value from child to parent doesn't work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using this amazing framework Ionic is , with Angular , on my first steps.
I'm trying to pass information from one of my components to one of the pages in the app using the child to parent communication, but eventually it didnt work.
Here is a sequence:

COUNTRIES.TS COMPONENT CHILD:

Here i just inicialize a array of countries to be looped in order to show in the ion select option,
as well as initiialize the Output process to emit whichever the value by the time this component emits, being of type string called countrySelected.
Then i initialize a function on click in order to see the event clicked on the option selected(this isn't working)

TS File

```typescript
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonSelect } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-countries',
  templateUrl: './countries.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./countries.component.scss'],
})
export class CountriesComponent implements OnInit {


  @Output()countrySelected=new EventEmitter<string>();

  countries:string[]=[
    "ae","ar","at","au","be","bg","br","ca","ch","cn","co","cu"]

    pais:string='us',

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit():void {
    console.log(this.chiuldcountry);
  }

  onClick(event){
    console.log(event);
    this.pais=event.target.value
    this.countrySelected.emit(this.pais)
 }
}
```

COUNTRIES.HTML COMPONENT CHILD:

Here i just loop over the array initialized in the ts, i asigned as well a triggering a function
to detect the click event and the data it carries(as optional alternative i used ionChange, but either case doesn't work)

HTML file

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-select [value]="pais" >
    <ion-select-option #country *ngFor="let country of countries" name ='country'   (click)="onClick($event)" [value]="country">{{country}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

TAB1.HTML PAGE PARENT:

Hera basically i just exposed (bound) the output brough in the child tag app-countries and i just
trigger the function  receiveCountryToSelect($event) that eventually might receive the emitted
child country value

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="dark">
     <ion-item>
      <app-countries (countrySelected)="receiveCountryToSelect($event)"></app-countries>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content color="dark">
...some code...
</ion-content>
```

TAB1.TS PAGE PARENT:

Then here i just trigger the function mentiones in the html receiveCountryToSelect, trying to asign
to the variable 'pais' whatever the value the child brings accessing the event.target.value

```typescript
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { IonSegment } from '@ionic/angular';
import { DataServiceService } from 'src/app/services/data-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: "app-tab2",
  templateUrl: "tab2.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["tab2.page.scss"],
})

export class Tab2Page implements OnInit {
 
  
  pais:string=''

  constructor(
    private dataService:DataServiceService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getAllNews(this.pais).subscribe(result=>{
      console.log(result);
    })
 }

receiveCountryToSelect(event){
    console.log(event);
    this.pais=event.target.value
  }
}
```

But for any reason , i can't make this to work, even the logs in order to see what gets triggered on the click don't work , being impossible to find a way

Any help would be amazing

im using IONIC and Angular.
Thanks

Comment: have you tried to change onClick name function ?

Comment: what does that have to do on the process?

Comment: i did it but didnýt work

Comment: Is the countries a modal?

Answer (score 0):

According to [ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select-option), `ion-select-option` does not emit any event.

As an alternative, I recommend handling `ionChange` event in `ion-select`.

```xml
    <ion-select (ionChange)="...">

    </ion-select>
```

References:

- ion-select-option: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select-option
- ion-select: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select